# Dropping a column in a dataframe based on the next column value not being a value in a given list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, where I have diagnosis code prefixed with `DIAGX` that come with diagnosis type prefixed with `DTYPX` as the next column/variable in the df. This is the case for 42 diagnosis code/type pairs.

I only want to include diagnosis codes `DIAGX` where their corresponding/next diagnosis type `DTYPX` are in a predefined list `types_to_include`.

E.g pat1 has a diagnosis type that I'm not interested in `DTYPX3 = 1` so I want to replace the diagnosis code `DIAGX3` value with NULL or blank so I don't include this in later code.

df_patients

```
patients = [('pat1', 'Z509', '3', 'M33', 'M', 'M32', 1,  'M315', 'Y'),
         ('pat2', 'I099', '3', 'I278', '6', 'M05', 'W', 'F01', 'M'),
         ('pat3', 'N057', '3', 'N057', 'M', 'N058', 'X', 'N057', 'X')]
labels = ['patient_num', 'DIAGX1', 'DTYPX1', 'DIAGX2', 'DTYPX2', 'DIAGX3', 'DTYPX3', 'DIAGX4', 'DTYPX4']
df_patients = pd.DataFrame.from_records(patients, columns=labels)
df_patients

Input
patient_num DIAGX1  DTYPX1  DIAGX2  DTYPX2  DIAGX3  DTYPX3  DIAGX4  DTYPX4
pat1        Z509    3       M33     M       M32     1       M315    Y
pat2        I099    3       I278    6       M05     4       F01     2
pat3        N057    3       N057    M       N058    X       N057    X

types_to_include = ['3', 'M', 'W', 'X', 'Y']

Output
patient_num DIAGX1  DTYPX1  DIAGX2  DTYPX2  DIAGX3  DTYPX3  DIAGX4  DTYPX4
pat1        Z509    3       M33     M       NULL    1       M315    Y
pat2        I099    3       NULL    6       NULL    4       NULL    2
pat3        N057    3       N057    M       N058    X       N057    X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
patients = [('pat1', 'Z509', '3', 'M33', 'M', 'M32', 1,  'M315', 'Y'),
         ('pat2', 'I099', '3', 'I278', '6', 'M05', '4', 'F01', '2'),
         ('pat3', 'N057', '3', 'N057', 'M', 'N058', 'X', 'N057', 'X')]
labels = ['patient_num', 'DIAGX1', 'DTYPX1', 'DIAGX2', 'DTYPX2', 'DIAGX3', 'DTYPX3', 'DIAGX4', 'DTYPX4']
df_patients = pd.DataFrame.from_records(patients, columns=labels)
types_to_include = ['3', 'M', 'W', 'X', 'Y']

# check if types to include are there
m = df_patients.filter(like='DTYPX').isin(types_to_include).values
# filter out the types that aren't there
new = df_patients.filter(like='DIAG').where(m, 'NULL')
# update df
df_patients.update(new)
df_patients
```

[image]